# write a Request using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

How can I retrieve the environment names  by given Platform names using JPA request (1 environment can be associated to n Plateform and 1 Platform can be associated to n Environmnt)?

```
public class HPe implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected HPePK hPePK;
@Column(name = "PE_TIMEOUT")
private Integer peTimeout;
@Column(name = "PE_STATUS")
private Boolean peStatus;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "hPe")
private Collection<HPesp> hPespCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "PE_ENV", referencedColumnName = "ENV_URL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private HEnv hEnv; // HEnv  classe name
@JoinColumn(name = "PE_PLATFORM", referencedColumnName = "PLATFORM_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private HPlatform hPlatform;  //HPlatform  classe name
}
```

Update
problem Resloved :

SELECT h.hPePK.peEnv FROM HPe h WHERE h.hPePK.pePlatform = :w

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you get an exception or a empty result with your statement?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
select hpe.hEnv.envName from HPe hpe where hpe.hPlatform.platName = :platName
```

(Use `platName` as parameter)

Maybe it needs something more like a `join` but please try first